# New GitHub organization isn't showing on my profile

Tags: github, profile

My new organization (created yesterday) is visible in my account settings:

[image: list of organizations]

but it isn't visible when viewing my profile:

[image: github profile]

Any idea why it's not showing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may need to declare or publicise your membership in the organisation.

1. Go to your team/organisation profile
2. Click on the **People** tab

   - The URL will be similar to: `https://github.com/orgs/{foo}/people`
3. Go to the line with your profile and change **Private** to **Public**

> [image: changing visibility]

The organisation will now appear on your profile and you will be listed publicly as a member when others are viewing the organisation's profile page.

Comment: Please share the direct URL to this page.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/publicizing-or-hiding-organization-membership/